# Numpy : Grouping/ binning values based on associations

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, array-broadcasting, numpy-ndarray

`Forgive me for a vague title. I honestly don't know which title will suit this question. If you have a better title, let's change it so that it will be apt for the problem at hand.`

### The problem.

Let's say `result` is a 2D array and `values` is a 1D array. `values` holds some values associated with each element in `result`. The mapping of an element in `values` to `result` is stored in `x_mapping` and `y_mapping`. A position in `result` can be associated with different values. Now, I have to find the sum of the values grouped by associations.

An example for better clarification.

`result` array:

```
[[0, 0],
[0, 0],
[0, 0],
[0, 0]]
```

`values` array:

```
[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.]
```

Note: Here `result` and `values` have the same number of elements. But it might not be the case. There is no relation between the sizes at all.

`x_mapping` and `y_mapping` have mappings from 1D `values` to 2D `result`. The sizes of `x_mapping`, `y_mapping` and `values` will be the same.

`x_mapping` - `[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`

`y_mapping` - `[0, 3, 2, 2, 0, 3, 2, 1]`

Here, 1st value(`values[0]`) have x as 0 and y as 0(`x_mapping[0]` and `y_mappping[0]`) and hence associated with `result[0, 0]`. If we are counting the number of associations, then element value at `result[0,0]` will be 2 as 1st value and 5th value are associated with `result[0, 0]`. If we are taking the sum, the `result[0, 0] = value[0] + value[4]` which is 6.

### Current solution

```
# Initialisation. No connection with the solution.
result = np.zeros([4,2], dtype=np.int16)

values =  np.linspace(start=1, stop=8, num=8)
y_mapping = np.random.randint(low=0, high=values.shape[0], size=values.shape[0])
x_mapping = np.random.randint(low=0, high=values.shape[1], size=values.shape[0])
# Summing the values associated with x,y (current solution.)
for i in range(values.size):
    x = x_mapping[i]
    y = y_mapping[i]
    result[-y, x] = result[-y, x] + values[i]
```

The `result`,

```
[[6, 0],
[ 6, 2],
[14, 0],
[ 8, 0]]
```

### Failed solution; But why?

```
test_result = np.zeros_like(result)
test_result[-y_mapping, x_mapping] = test_result[-y_mapping, x_mapping] + values # solution
```

To my surprise elements are overwritten in `test_result`. Values at `test_result`,

```
[[5, 0],
[6, 2],
[7, 0],
[8, 0]]
```

### Question

#### 1. Why, in the second solution, every element is overwritten?

As @Divakar has pointed out in the comment in his answer - 
NumPy doesn't assign accumulated/summed values when the indices are repeated in `test_result[-y_mapping, x_mapping] =`. It randomly assigns from one of the instances.

#### 2. Is there any Numpy way to do this? That is without looping? I'm looking for some speed optimization.

Approach #2 in @Divakar's answer gives me good results. For 23315 associations, `for` loop took 50 ms while Approach #1 took 1.85 ms. Beating all these, Approach #2 took 668 µs.

### Side note

I'm using Numpy version 1.14.3 with Python 3.5.2 on an i7 processor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach #1**

Most intutive one would be with `np.add.at` for those repeated indices -

```
np.add.at(result, [-y_mapping, x_mapping], values)
```

**Approach #2**

We need to perform binned summations owing to the possible repeated nature of x,y indices. Hence, another way could be to use NumPy's binned summation func : `np.bincount` and have an implementation like so -

```
# Get linear index equivalents off the x and y indices into result array
m,n = result.shape
out_dtype = result.dtype
lidx = ((-y_mapping)%m)*n + x_mapping

# Get binned summations off values based on linear index as bins
binned_sums = np.bincount(lidx, values, minlength=m*n)

# Finally add into result array
result += binned_sums.astype(result.dtype).reshape(m,n)
```

If you are always starting off with a zeros array for `result`, the last step could be made more performant with -

```
result = binned_sums.astype(out_dtype).reshape(m,n)
```

Comment: Thank you Divakar for the reply. Any insights on why the second approach failed?

Comment: @tpk NumPy doesn't assign accumulated/summed values when the indices are repeated in `test_result[-y_mapping, x_mapping] =`. It randomly assigns from one of the instances.

Comment: any suggestions on tutorials to learn more on `np.bincount` other than official documentation?

Comment: In the meantime, Let me compare the runtime and get back to you. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: @tpk Hmm, I couldn't find any with considerable info. At its core. it operates on 1D arrays and sums values based on the bins.

Comment: the second approach(668 µs) is much faster than the first approach(1.85 ms) for processing 23315 associations.

Comment: Is there any similar methods to find the maximum and minimum values from the bins?

Comment: @tpk There's `np.minimum.reduceat` and `np.maximum.reduceat`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177471/discussion-between-tpk-and-divakar).

Comment: can you look into this question as well?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53513497/numpy-finding-count-of-distinct-values-from-associations-through-binning

Answer (score 0):

I guess you were to write

```
y_mapping = np.random.randint(low=0, high=result.shape[0], size=values.shape[0])
x_mapping = np.random.randint(low=0, high=result.shape[1], size=values.shape[0])
```

With that correction, the code works for me as expected.

Comment: Hello tif, Thanks for pointing out the error in the `current solution`. I have corrected the naming. Here, I'm looking for an alternative solution which will be much faster than the current implementation. Thanks.