# Numpy: Finding minimum and maximum values from associations through binning

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting, numpy-ufunc

### Prerequisite

This is a question derived from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51691980/numpy-grouping-binning-values-based-on-associations). So, some of the introduction of the problem will be similar to that post.

### Problem

Let's say `result` is a 2D array and `values` is a 1D array. `values` holds some values associated with each element in `result`. The mapping of an element in `values` to `result` is stored in `x_mapping` and `y_mapping`. A position in `result` can be associated with different values. Now, I have to find the minimum and maximum of the values grouped by associations.

An example for better clarification.

`min_result` array:

```
[[0, 0],
[0, 0],
[0, 0],
[0, 0]]
```

`max_result` array:

```
[[0, 0],
[0, 0],
[0, 0],
[0, 0]]
```

`values` array:

```
[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.]
```

Note: Here `result` arrays and `values` have the same number of elements. But it might not be the case. There is no relation between the sizes at all.

`x_mapping` and `y_mapping` have mappings from 1D `values` to 2D `result`(both min and max). The sizes of `x_mapping`, `y_mapping` and `values` will be the same.

`x_mapping` - `[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`

`y_mapping` - `[0, 3, 2, 2, 0, 3, 2, 1]`

Here, 1st value(`values[0]`) and 5th value(`values[4]`) have x as 0 and y as 0(`x_mapping[0]` and `y_mappping[0]`) and hence associated with `result[0, 0]`. If we compute the minimum and maximum from this group, we will have 1 and 5 as results respectively. So, `min_result[0, 0]` will have 1 and `max_result[0, 0]` will have 5.

Note that if there is no association at all then the default value for `result` will be zero.

### Current working solution

```
x_mapping = np.array([0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
y_mapping = np.array([0, 3, 2, 2, 0, 3, 2, 1])
values = np.array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.], dtype=np.float32)
max_result = np.zeros([4, 2], dtype=np.float32)
min_result = np.zeros([4, 2], dtype=np.float32) 
min_result[-y_mapping, x_mapping] = values # randomly initialising from values
for i in range(values.size):
    x = x_mapping[i]
    y = y_mapping[i]
    # maximum
    if values[i] > max_result[-y, x]:
        max_result[-y, x] = values[i]
    # minimum
    if values[i] < min_result[-y, x]:
        min_result[-y, x] = values[i]
```

`min_result`,

```
[[1., 0.],
[6., 2.],
[3., 0.],
[8., 0.]]
```

`max_result`,

```
[[5., 0.],
[6., 2.],
[7., 0.],
[8., 0.]]
```

### Failed solutions

#### #1

```
min_result = np.zeros([4, 2], dtype=np.float32)
np.minimum.reduceat(values, [-y_mapping, x_mapping], out=min_result)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-126de899a90e> in <module>()
1 min_result = np.zeros([4, 2], dtype=np.float32)
----> 2 np.minimum.reduceat(values, [-y_mapping, x_mapping], out=min_result)

ValueError: object too deep for desired array
```

#### #2

```
min_result = np.zeros([4, 2], dtype=np.float32)
np.minimum.reduceat(values, lidx, out= min_result)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-07e8c75ccaa5> in <module>()
1 min_result = np.zeros([4, 2], dtype=np.float32)
----> 2 np.minimum.reduceat(values, lidx, out= min_result)

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with remapped shapes [original->remapped]: (4,2)->(4,) (8,)->() (8,)->(8,)
```

#### #3

```
lidx = ((-y_mapping) % 4) * 2 + x_mapping #from mentioned post
min_result = np.zeros([8], dtype=np.float32)
np.minimum.reduceat(values, lidx, out= min_result).reshape(4,2)

[[1., 4.],
[5., 5.],
[1., 3.],
[5., 7.]]
```

### Question

How to use `np.minimum.reduceat` and `np.maximum.reduceat` for solving this problem? I'm looking for a solution that is optimised for runtime.

### Side note

I'm using Numpy version 1.14.3 with Python 3.5.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach #1**

Again, the most intuitive ones would be with [`numpy.ufunc.at`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html).
Now, since, these reductions would be performed against the existing values, we need to initialize the output with max values for minimum reductions and min values for maximum ones. Hence, the implementation would be -

```
min_result[-y_mapping, x_mapping] = values.max()
max_result[-y_mapping, x_mapping] = values.min()

np.minimum.at(min_result, [-y_mapping, x_mapping], values)
np.maximum.at(max_result, [-y_mapping, x_mapping], values)
```

**Approach #2**

To leverage `np.ufunc.reduceat`, we need to sort data -

```
m,n = max_result.shape
out_dtype = max_result.dtype
lidx = ((-y_mapping)%m)*n + x_mapping

sidx = lidx.argsort()
idx = lidx[sidx]
val = values[sidx]

m_idx = np.flatnonzero(np.r_[True,idx[:-1] != idx[1:]])
unq_ids = idx[m_idx]

max_result_out.flat[unq_ids] = np.maximum.reduceat(val, m_idx)
min_result_out.flat[unq_ids] = np.minimum.reduceat(val, m_idx)
```

Comment: `np.minimum.at(min_result, [-y_mapping, x_mapping], values)` will result in zero array if we initialise the `min_result` as zero. Any workaround other than `min_result[min_result == MAX_VALUE] = 0.0`?

Comment: The second approach is much faster than first. Any insights?

Comment: @tpk Same as in the previous question. `ufunc.at` ones are probably looping under the hoods as opposed to `ufunc.reduceat` which aren't.

Comment: can you look into this question as well?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53513497/numpy-finding-count-of-distinct-values-from-associations-through-binning